# How to send boolean value from perl script without converting them into string

Tags: json, perl, boolean

I pass a Perl data structure to `encode_json`, and use its returned value as a input to post to restful API.

Example:

```
$data = (input1 => true);
$json_data = encode_json($data);
print $json_data; // Prints: ["input1":"true"]

$url= http://api.example.com/resources/getDataAPI
$headers = {Accept => 'application/json', Authorization => 'Basic ' . encode_base64($username . ':' . $password)};

$client = REST::Client->new();
$client->POST($url,($json_data,$headers));
```

This was working all fine.

Recently another developer made few input parameter validations checks, and REST strictly accepts Boolean value, without quotes.

I need now to send my input as

```
$data = '["inout1":true]'
$client = REST::Client->new();
$client->POST($url,($data,$headers));
```

All my scripts are failing as input data is encoded into JSON format using `encode_json` function.

I can form a JSON data manually, but the input data would be sometimes very huge. Can not identify them and modify ever time.

Is there any way I can achieve passing Boolean value without quotation marks?

Comment: See https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON#PERL-%3E-JSON

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Using `true` and `false` directly in Perl is a syntax error under `use strict` because *barewords* are then not allowed.

I guess you are using [JSON](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON) or [JSON::XS](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON::XS). Those use *scalar references* to indicate `TRUE` and `FALSE`. Specifically, `\1` and `\0`.

```
$data = ( input1 => \1 );
```

Here's the relevant [doc from JSON::XS](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON::XS#Types::Serialiser::true,-Types::Serialiser::false), which allows [Types::Serializer::True](https://metacpan.org/pod/Types::Serialiser) and Types::Serializer::False as well:

> These special values from the Types::Serialiser module become JSON true and JSON false values, respectively. You can also use `\1` and `\0` directly if you want.

And [the doc from JSON](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON#JSON::true,-JSON::false,-JSON::null), where `JSON::true` and `JSON::false` can also be used:

> These special values become JSON true and JSON false values, respectively. You can also use `\1` and `\0` directly if you want.

---

If you insist on using `true` without quotes as in `my $foo = true`, you could make subs or constants (which are really subs) that return `\1` and `\0`.

```
use constant false => \0;
sub true () { return \1 } # note the empty prototype

$data = ( input1 => true, input2 => false );
```

As [Sinan points out in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43867553/how-to-send-boolean-value-from-perl-script-without-converting-them-into-string/43867848?noredirect=1#comment74773461_43867848), it's faster to use a constant, unless you include an empty prototype (the `()` in the sub definition), because that way Perl can inline the call.

But in my opinion that is less clear than simply using the references. Always think about the next guy working on this code.

Comment: `use constant false` creates a subroutine that can be inlined where as `sub true` gets invoked each time. The equivalent would be `sub true () { \1 }` so long as the prototype is seen before code that uses it.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know that.

Comment: @Borodin which part? What Sinan said, or what I said? I didn't know the inlining (is that a word?!) thing either. Trying it out now.

Comment: The thing about inlining is documented under [*Constant Functions* in `perlsub`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Constant-Functions) I meant about the references for JSON booleans. I have always used `JSON::true` and `JSON;;false`.

Comment: I'll second @Borodin in that `JSON::true` and `JSON::false` are more helpful to the future reader of the code than `\0` and `\1`.

Comment: @SinanÜnür but they are less portable. If you switch to a different JSON implementation that might break. In any case, those should be better than using the constant.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, `JSON->true` and `JSON->false` should work with all JSON modules. If inlining did matter, I would actually just do `use constant _JSON_true => JSON->true` and `use constant _JSON_false => JSON->false` in my code, instead of having bare `\0` and `\1`. In my experience, people tend to freak out a little when they see things like that.

Answer (score 3):

Contrary to the answer from [simbabque](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1331451/simbabque), I really don't think it's a good idea to use references as `\1` and `\0` to produce `true` and `false` in JSON.

The constants from the [JSON module](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON#JSON::true,-JSON::false,-JSON::null) are there for more than just convenience.

If you use such constants, you can still evaluate them as `true` or `false` values in Perl, while both `\0` and `\1` are evaluated a `true` in Perl.

And using those constants, besides keeping the boolean value in Perl, will work in JSON to produce the right data.

Here's an example of what I'm saying:

```
use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON qw(encode_json decode_json);

my $data = {
    true_1 => JSON::true,
    true_2 => \1,
    false_1 => JSON::false,
    false_2 => \0,
};

for my $key (sort keys %$data) {
    say "$key value is $data->{$key} and is evaluated as true" if $data->{$key};
    say "$key value is $data->{$key} and is evaluated as false" if not $data->{$key};
}

say encode_json $data;
```

That code will output something like this:

```
false_1 value is 0 and is evaluated as false
false_2 value is SCALAR(0x146f39b4c18) and is evaluated as true

true_1 value is 1 and is evaluated as true
true_2 value is SCALAR(0x146f3998918) and is evaluated as true

{"true_2":true,"false_1":false,"false_2":false,"true_1":true}
```

As you can see, the value with a reference to `\0` (`false_2`) is evaluated as **`true`** in Perl, while the value that was set as `JSON::false` is still `false` in Perl evaluations.

Also, you can see that, when printing the value of `JSON::true` and `JSON::false`, they are automatically converted into `1` and `0`, while `\1` and `\0` are printed as `SCALAR(0x146f3998918)` and `SCALAR(0x146f39b4c18)`.

At the end, both work correctly when converted into `JSON`. But setting "true" values in a Perl data structure that are supposed to be false (`0`, empty string or `undef`), can cause you bugs in other parts of your code where you might be using the same structure and evaluating boolean fields to do something.

Also, at development level, it's much more easier for a peer developer to understand what you are coding when using `JSON::true` and `JSON::false`, than seeing references as `\1` and `\0` and not being able to understand the reason of the reference if he/she is not familiar with such a hacky trick.

If you really want to save yourself from typing those extra 6 characters, then you can do this at the top of your code:

```
use JSON qw(encode_json decode_json);
sub true () { JSON::true }
sub false () { JSON::false }
```

And then you can simply use them as constants in your code, like this:

```
$data = {
    is_member => true,
    is_suspended => false,
}
```

Although, maybe constant names should be named in all uppercase (like `TRUE` and `FALSE`), but that's a subject for a different discussion.

So, always use `JSON::true` and `JSON::false` when working with Perl and JSON. They will evaluate well in Perl, they are converted into the right data type in JSON, and they print correctly to console and files. Same thing goes for `JSON::null`.